# Practical Chemo Opus

Tags: word-property, chemistry

Herb Clark likes few substances, such as:

CARBON, NEON, SILICON, PHOSPHORUS, IRON, COPPER, ARSENIC, KRYPTON, ...

Find others per inclination.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Herb likes substances that

> can be spelled using chemical element abbreviations. He likes the entire question, because every single word in it can be written that way!
>
>  Some other substances he likes are `WAtEr` and `FIRe`, but he doesn't like EARTH or AIR.

Comment: I wonder if he also likes horrible things like POISON, VIRUS and CANCER :)

Answer (score 7):

Another in the list might be

> TIN

Reasoning

> Herb Clark likes chemical elements whose names can be formed with a combination of chemical symbols.

Examples

> CARBON = Ca + Rb + O + N.
>  PHOSPHORUS = P + Ho + S + P + Ho + Ru + S.
>  IRON = Ir + O + N.
>  KRYPTON = Kr + Y + Pt + O + N.

Comment: @Deusovi beat you by 25 seconds!

Comment: @JeremyDover Ha! I need to learn to type quicker.

Comment: Me too. It took me 5 times longer to write it than it did for you guys to answer it :-)

Comment: I think if you stick to the Periodic Table, ArSeNiC also fits @hexomino

Comment: @DEEM Oh, yes, sorry, I just listed some of them as examples, they can of course all be formed this way.